# Cross platform over LAN

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I've got some friends on PC and some on Mac, however whilse some Mac friends have the steam version, most have the mac app store version.

Is there a way to play (Civ5, BNW) between these groups. 
Other questions didn't definitively answer this; I understand that we can't share a pitboss or play over the internet, but what about a local network? 
If the issue is steam DRM or clients, shouldn't local network lack that?

If a local network can work, could I set up a sort of "local internet"; spatially distanced players but we all access a closed infranet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not? I don't have access to a copy of the Mac Version but have dug up some info.

Bad news from in the [Mac app store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/civilization-v-campaign-edition/id439924718?mt=12)

> Currently multiplayer is played via Mac to Mac LAN play only.

And on [Civ Fanatics](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/faq-for-civ5-players-with-mac-computers.403978/)

> Cross platform multiplayer will ONLY work between the Steam versions.

However, there is hope:

> The Mac AppStore version only supports cross-platform play on a LAN when the AppStore and Windows versions are the same.

Although they note:

> The AppStore version is 1.0.3.144 as of December 18, 2013
>   The Steam version is 1.0.3.276 as of October 27, 2014

This is out of date, as my Steam version is 1.0.3.279 as of December, 2016. If that matches the current Mac version then you should be able to play together, otherwise you just can't.